# ERR_BAD_REQUEST - Code 400: NFT Marketplace: createNFT function using Pinata not work

Tags: node.js, axios, web3js, nft, pinata

I have created an NFT function using Pinata.
With My code, I can upload images to Pinata, but when I add metadata and call create-NFT function, I always facing
ERR_BAD_REQUEST: 400 Bad Request (as below picture)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKBTK.png)

Do you know how to solve this error?
I have already checked the API Key and the Secret Key is correct.

Here is my code:

1. uploadToIPFS function:

```
//@dev: Upload to IPFS function
  const uploadToIPFS = async (file) => {
    if (file) {
      try {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("file", file);

        const resFile = await axios({
          method: "post",
          url: "https://api.pinata.cloud/pinning/pinFileToIPFS",
          data: formData,
          headers: {
            pinata_api_key: key,
            pinata_secret_key: secret_key,
            "Content-Type": `multipart/form-data`,
            Authorization: `Bearer ${pinata_JWT}`,
          },
        });

        const imgHash = `https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/${resFile.data.IpfsHash}`;
        console.log(imgHash);
        return imgHash;
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error while uploading to IPFS", error);
      }
    }
  };
```

2. createNFT function

```
//@dev: Create NFT function
  const createNFT = async (name, price, image, description, router) => {
    if (!name || !description || !price || !image) {
      console.log("Data Is Missing");
      return;
    }
    const data = JSON.stringify({ name, description, image });

    try {
      const resFile = await axios({
        method: "POST",
        url: "https://api.pinata.cloud/pinning/pinFileToIPFS",
        data: data,
        headers: {
          pinata_api_key: key,
          pinata_secret_key: secret_key,
          "Content-Type": `application/json`,
          Authorization: `Bearer ${pinata_JWT}`,
        },
      });
      
      // Upload image file to Pinata IPFS
      const imgHash = `https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/${resFile.data.IpfsHash}`;
      console.log(imgHash);

      await createSale(imgHash, price);
      router.push("/searchPage");
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error while creating NFT:", error);
    }
  };
```

3. createSale function

```
//@dev: createSale function
  const createSale = async (url, formInputPrice, isReselling, id) => {
    try {
      console.log(url, formInputPrice, isReselling, id);
      const price = ethers.utils.parseUnits(formInputPrice, "ether");
      const contract = await connectingWithSmartContract();

      const listingPrice = await contract.getListingPrice();

      const transaction = !isReselling
        ? await contract.createToken(url, price, {
            value: listingPrice.toString(),
          })
        : await contract.reSellToken(url, price, {
            value: listingPrice.toString(),
          });

      await transaction.wait();
      console.log(transaction);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error while creating sale");
    }
  };
```

I followed to youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w3IsLQxXTvo&t=561s

Do you know how to solve this error?
I have already checked the API Key and the Secret Key is correct.
And my code can upload NFT images to Pinata.
But when calling the create-NFT function, this error happens.

Answer (score 1):

I have update my code with below and it working fine. The reason Request invalid because the API Pinata in below is not valid for JSON file added.

```
url: "https://api.pinata.cloud/pinning/pinFileToIPFS",
```

My code after update:

```
url: "https://api.pinata.cloud/pinning/pinJSONToIPFS",
```